# Is the set of discrete probability measures with exactly $n$ atoms Borel measurable?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(E, d)$ be a compact metric space and $\mathcal P(E)$ the space of Borel probability measures on $E$. We endow $\mathcal P(E)$ with topology of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures?useskin=vector#Weak_convergence_of_measures). Let

- $\mathcal G_n (E)$ be the space of **discrete** probability measures on $E$ whose supports contain **at most** $n$ atoms. This means $\mathcal G_n (E)$ contains those measures $\nu$ of the form $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \delta_{x_i}$ where $(p_1, \ldots, p_n) \in \Delta^{n-1}$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in E$.
- $\mathcal G'_n (E)$ be the space of **discrete** probability measures on $E$ whose supports contain **exactly** $n$ atoms. This means $\mathcal G'_n (E)$ contains those measures $\nu$ of the form $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \delta_{x_i}$ where $(p_1, \ldots, p_n) \in \Delta^{n-1}$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in E$ such that $p_i>0$ for all $i =1, \ldots,n$ and that $x_i= x_j \iff i=j$.

Then $\mathcal G_n (E)$ is closed and $\mathcal G'_n (E)$ is not closed. Clearly, $\mathcal G_n (E)$ is Borel measurable.

> Could you elaborate on if $\mathcal G'_n (E)$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $\mathcal G'_n (E)=\mathcal G_n (E)\setminus \mathcal G_{n-1} (E)$?

Comment: @geetha290krm You are right! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Borel because $\mathcal G'_n (E)=\mathcal G_n (E)\setminus \mathcal G_{n-1} (E)$.